# How to add similar objects into an array?

Tags: java, arrays, object, addition

I have a bunch of similar objects (cards for a game to be specific), and want to add them to an array. Copying them all by hand seems pretty elaborate, so is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
// the card objects, first number is identifier, rest is information
// the name "card1" etc. come from another part and cant be changed by me!
static Card card1 = new Card(1, "xyz", 0, 3);
static Card card2 = new Card(2, "wer", 1, 1);
static Card card3 = new Card(3, "gub", 0, 0);
...
static Card card100 = new Card(100, "sdf", 4, 0);

// here the cards get added
static Card stapel[] = new Card[] { card1, card2, card3, ... , card100 };
```

**EDIT1**: I have accepted jrahhalis answer now. After re-thinking what I wanted to accomplish it's wrong the insist on keeping the cards as "card1, card2, ...". It's much easier to just another array and put them into that.

Comment: you could add them in a loop?

Comment: But how? They are written as similar objects, not directly into an array. So I dont see how I can "grab" them for a loop.

Comment: from where are you getting values like xyz, wer, gub etc?

Comment: From another part of the game, that I dont develop. So I cant change the cards that I get.

Comment: I don't think it's possible in Java. You have to type each Card manually.

Comment: I hope you are wrong. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cuts down on a little bit of code.  Instead assigning your cards to variables, and then putting those variables into an array, you define and assign at the same time:

```
public class SomeClass {
    static Card stapel[] = new Card[100];

    public SomeClass() {
        stapel[0]  = new Card(1, "xyz", 0, 3);
        stapel[1]  = new Card(2, "wer", 1, 1);
        stapel[2]  = new Card(3, "gub", 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this indeed does save me some code.
But it does not solve my problem, the cards need to stay as "card1", "card2" etc. for another part of the program that I dont develop.

Comment: I have accepted this as the answer now. Insisting on keeping "card1, card2, ..." was wrong, as using an array this way is much easier in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

You can go 2 ways:
- Either you use the reflection API to look up all the Card fields inside your class and add them to an array. ( I don't recommend this)
- You find a way to generate your Card objects dynamically. It will look something like this:

```
boolean cardsCompleted = false;
int nr = 0;
List<Card> stapel = new ArrayList<>();

while(! cardsCompleted) {
   nr++;
   Card temp = new Card(nr,"xyz", 0,0) //You will have to find a way to generate its parameters
   stapel.add(temp);
   if(nr==52)
    cardsCompleted = true;
 }
```

Small remark, the fact that your Card objects are declared static feels like your not applying a clean object oriented coding approach.

Comment: The cards need to be put into the ArrayList as "card1, card2 etc.", so this does not solve my problem. But thanks for the input about the static declaration, will look into that!

Comment: Could you elaborate why you object has to have a certain name? I can't think of any reason why you would want that :) Other parts of your code won't know the name you assigned to your object inside of your list. If the name is important to you, maybe create a fiel 'name' inside your Card class?

Comment: Because I get the card objects from another part of the programm, process them and then pass them on to another part of the programm. The input- and output-part are not developed by me, I cant change them. So creating a "name"-field wont help me. The data structure has to be like I described in my first post.

Comment: The structure I provide in my example differs in the way that it produces an arraylist with cards and not an array. For the rest the structure is the same. If you need an array you can call the `.toArray()` method on the arraylist afterwards.

Comment: The data structure contains the names too ("card1, card2, etc"), which is not reproduced by your method. Therefore this wont solve my problem.
Also the "//You will have to find a way to generate its parameters" part in your code means I have the almost exact same problem again - putting parameters I already have into an array (or arraylist).

Answer (score 1):

What about using the ArrayList Object?

```
ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Cards>;
cards.add(new Card(100, "sdf", 4, 0));
cards.add(new Card(2, "wer", 1, 1));
cards.add(new Card(3, "gub", 0, 0));
```

Comment: Hm, I dont think I can use this to solve my problem. The cards need to stay "card1, card2, card3, etc." as they are used in another part of the game that I dont develop.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach would be to research the factory design pattern. Once you are familiar with this concept you can insert the data as a string parameter.

In the long run you could transition into the factory design pattern for a lot of your code and you will be a better programmer because of it.

Check out Head First Design Patterns you can find the pdf version if you google it